# Haproxy http-buffer-request not working

Tags: haproxy

I can't get [Haproxys http-buffer-request option](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#option%20http-buffer-request) working. I'm using Haproxy 1.6.5. This is my configuration:

```
global
  maxconn 20000
  debug

defaults HTTP
  mode  http
  option  http-buffer-request  # buffer the whole request before dispatching it to the backend
  timeout connect  5s
  timeout client  50s
  timeout server  50s

frontend http
  bind 127.0.0.1:8123
  use_backend api.radioadmin_backend if { hdr(host) -i api.radioadmin.local:8123 }
  use_backend radioadmin_backend if { hdr(host) -i radioadmin.local:8123 }

backend api.radioadmin_backend
  mode  http
  server api.radioadmin3000 127.0.0.1:3000 check

backend radioadmin_backend
  mode  http
  server radioadmin3001 127.0.0.1:3001 check
```

However the request doesn't get buffered in Haproxy but dispatched directly to the app:

I'm running a Ruby app with Unicorn. The Unicorn workers get killed, if it takes them longer than 10 seconds to process a request. I'm uploading a file with Chrome and I throttle the bandwidth in the dev tools. I expected Haproxy to buffer the POST request until it's complete and only then dispatch it to the Ruby app. But it doesn't. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

tldr; It doesn't. Use NGinX.

Meanwhile I got an [answer from the Haproxy mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/28443). Thanks, Holger Just for the reply.

(Meta: I wasn't even sure the mailing list is still functional because I got errors back when posting to the list.)

If I had read the documentation carefully perhaps this sentence wouldn't have slipped my attention:

> This option placed in a frontend or backend forces the HTTP processing to wait until either the whole body is received, or the request buffer is full, or the first chunk is complete in case of chunked encoding.

This simply means Haproxy will never buffer large upload bodys entirely. The advice on the mailing list was to use NGinX for that.

I still don't understand how Haproxy can [protect against slow POST attacks](http://blog.haproxy.com/2016/02/10/what-is-a-slow-post-attack-and-how-turn-haproxy-into-your-first-line-of-defense/). I think an attacker simply would have slow down the data rate after the first chunk. But this discussion is beyond this question.

Comment: The mailing list is quite active; which errors did you get back then? IIRC, one has to be subscribed to post.

Comment: I accidentally delete the thread locally. My fault. The error was something like "Couldn't deliver mail. File /var/spool/mail/haproxy-archive too large". I figured it had something to do with the linked (on http://www.haproxy.org/) mailing list archive (http://marc.info/?l=haproxy) ending on 2015/12/01. But that's just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks. Seems the archive is broken, or maybe there is not disk space left over. I'll report this.

Comment: Another link to the mentioned mail question & answer: https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg23074.html

Comment: "I still don't understand how Haproxy can protect against slow POST attacks." [The mailing list has an answer for this](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg21475.html), the gist being `option http-buffer-request` with `timeout http-request`. Unfortunately it does not explicitly states what happens when the buffer is full (does the timeout still applies or is it released?).